# Wix.com database: Referencing multiple parts of a text in a single field to different fields

Tags: database, velo

Using wix.com databases I want to link multiple names appearing in a text field to independent fields. 
I know it is possible to reference a field to multiple fields through multiple-item reference fields. However I would like to link only some words of a text within one field to different elements (links to websites). Is this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: have you used the correct tag here? [tag:wix] is for Windows Installer Xml. Did you mean [tag:wix.com] instead?

Comment: thanks, yes, I mean wix.com!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the inner html of a text to achieve that:

```
const value = 'Stunning'

$w('#text1').html = '<div style="font-size:16px;">
                     Wix Sites are 
                     <a style="font-weight:bold;" href="http://wix.com" 
                     target="_blank">' + value +'</a>!</div>'
```

You can fetch the data from your collection using wix-data API and then do use it in the links texts.